# To add contacts to sub domain using Google API

Tags: delegates, google-people-api

I need to add contacts in bulk to subdomain gsuite account using Google API but I am getting any specific technique or method that can be used to add contacts in sub domain account. As I have the domain account access so changing in sub domain should be easy.

I want to the requirements need to create this method. I need to know the URL endpoints, scopes, and permission and also access token require to complete this method. I just need a clue how it can be done.

Comment: As said I want to add contact in sub domain gmail account using google api as I a have the domain account